# Find a finite union $U$ of open intervals

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the following: If $f$ is a bounded function on $[0,2\pi]$ and $A\subset[0,2\pi]$ a measurable set, then $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ a finite union $U$ of open intervals s.t. $|\int_Uf-\int_Af|<\epsilon$.

I have difficulties to show, that there is a $U$ which has such a form. I considered two cases:

1. If $(0,\pi)\subset A\subset[0,\pi]$, take $U=(0,2\pi)$, then $\mu(A\setminus U)=0$ and I can show the claim.  (I even don't need that $f$ is bounded for this case?)
2. In the other case, I know that $\forall\delta>0\ \exists U\subset[0,2\pi]$ open s.t. $A\subset U$ and $\mu(U\setminus A)<\delta$ because $A$ is measurable. If I take $\delta=\epsilon/M$ (where $M$ is the bound of $f$) I can show the claim for this $U$. But in general this is an arbitrary union of open intervals? How can I find a finite one?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it would be easier to show this by regularity of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. You know that since $f$ is bounded, that there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\lambda(E)<\delta$ then $\int_E \vert f\vert< \frac{1}{4} \epsilon$. By regularity there exists a closed subset $F\subseteq A$ such that $\lambda(A\setminus F)< \frac{\delta}{2} $. $F$ is a compact set, hence for the open cover $\{ (x-\frac{\delta}{2}),x+\frac{\delta}{2}  \}_{x\in F} $, there exists a finite subcover of open intervals, and define it's union $U$. The measure of $U\Delta A$ will be less than $\delta$, hence by the triangle inequality you will obtain what you need.

Approximating $A$ by a closed subset (which is also compact) is the additional step you need.

Comment: +1...Based on some or the Q's I've seen on this site, there seems to be a modern teaching style in measure theory that avoids inner regularity and inner measure.

Comment: I still have some questions to your answer: How can I see, that $U\subset [0,2\pi]$? and how can I proceed with the triangle equality? I have difficulties to express $|\int_Uf-\int_Af|$ in terms of the symmetric difference

Comment: $U$ is not necessarily a subset of $[0,2\pi]$ but $A$ could be $[0,2\pi]$ and the for this case $F=A$, and every open cover of $A$ would strictly contain $[0,2\pi]$. But you can extend $f$ to a bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\tilde{f}=f\cdot \chi_{[0,2\pi]}$.

Comment: We can write: $\vert \int_U\tilde{f}-\int_A \tilde{f}\vert=\Big\vert -\int_{A\setminus U} \tilde{f}+\int_{U\setminus A}\tilde {f}\Big\vert \leq \int_{U\Delta A} \vert \tilde{f}\vert \overset{\lambda(U\Delta A)<\delta}{<}\epsilon$.

Comment: I know it was a long time ago, but I stil have one question: How do you show, that $\lambda(U\triangle A)<\delta$?  $\lambda(U\triangle A)\leq \lambda(U\setminus F)+\lambda(A\setminus F)$ and the second summand is smaller then $\frac{\delta}{2}$. But what can you say about the first term? If $F$ is for example a finite set of $n$ points, where the points are far apart then the measure of $U\setminus F$ is $n\delta$ because you are just deleting the middle Point of each of the intervals from the cover which doesn't change the measure...